# remove commas from string

Tags: c++, string

I created a program in C++ that remove commas (`,`) from a given integer. i.e. `2,00,00` would return `20000`. I am not using any new space. Here is the program I created:

```
void removeCommas(string& str1, int len)
{
    int j = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (str1[i] == ',')
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            str1[j] = str1[i];
            j++;
        }
    }

    str1[j] = '\0';
}

void main()
{
    string str1;
    getline(cin, str1);
    int i = str1.length();
    removeCommas(str1, i);
    cout << "the new string " << str1 << endl;
}
```

Here is the result I get:

```
Input : 2,000,00
String length  =8
Output = 200000 0
Length = 8
```

My question is that why does it show the length has `8` in output and shows the rest of string when I did put a null character. It should show output as `200000` and length has `6`.

Comment: Your alleged output doesn't match what your included code actually does.

Comment: You really haven't gotten a single useful answer to any of your other questions?

Answer (score 18):

Let the standard library do the work for you:

```
#include <algorithm>

str1.erase(std::remove(str1.begin(), str1.end(), ','), str1.end());
```

If you don't want to modify the original string, that's easy too:

```
std::string str2(str1.size(), '0');
str2.erase(std::remove_copy(str1.begin(), str1.end(), str2.begin(), ','), str2.end());
```

Comment: `remove_copy` should be much faster than anything that uses `erase`.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Possibly, but I didn't have that right.  I'll fix it.

Comment: I still needed `erase` with `remove_copy` unless I used `back_inserter`.  But I suspect `erase` is faster than having to grow the string multiple times.

Comment: Depends on the number of erasures.  If you are removing M elements from a list of N items, `erase` is O(MN), while `back_inserter` is O(N) with a slightly greater constant term.  And calling `reserve` before `back_inserter` gets you the best of both worlds.

Comment: Sorry, it's `remove`, not `erase`, that ends up moving items around.  But just calling `resize` should be faster than `erase`.

Answer (score 8):

You need to do a resize instead at the end.

Contrary to popular belief an std::string CAN contain binary data including 0s. An std::string 's `.size()` is not related to the string containing a NULL termination.

```
std::string s("\0\0", 2);
assert(s.size() == 2);
```

Answer (score 4):

The answer is probably that `std::string`s aren't NUL-terminated.  Instead of setting the end+1'th character to '\0', you should use `str.resize(new_length);`.

Edit: Also consider that, if your source string has no commas in it, then your '\0' will be written one past the end of the string (which will probably just happen to work, but is incorrect).

Answer (score 1):

The std::srting does not terminate with `\0`, you are mixing this with char* in C. So you should use [resize](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/resize/).

Answer (score 1):

The solution has already been posted by Fred L.

In a "procedural fashion" (without "algorithm")
your program would look like:

```
void removeStuff(string& str, char character)
{
 size_t pos;
 while( (pos=str.find(character)) != string::npos )
      str.erase(pos, 1);
}

 void main()
{
 string str1;
 getline(cin, str1);
 removeStuff(str1, ',');
 cout<<"the new string "<<str1<<endl;
}
```

then.

Regards

rbo

**EDIT / Addendum:**

In order to adress some efficiency concerns of readers,
I tried to come up with the fastest solution possible.
Of course, this should kick in on string sizes over
about 10^5 characters with some characters to-be-removed
included:

```
 void fastRemoveStuff(string& str, char character)
{
 size_t len = str.length();
 char *t, *buffer = new char[len];
 const char *p, *q;

 t = buffer, p = q = str.data();
 while( p=(const char*)memchr(q, character, len-(p-q)) ) {
     memcpy(t, q, p-q);
     t += p-q, q = p+1;
 }
 if( q-str.data() != len ) {
     size_t tail = len - (q-str.data());
     memcpy(t, q, tail);
     t += tail;
 }
 str.assign(buffer, t-buffer);
 delete [] buffer;
}

 void main()
{
 string str1 = "56,4,44,55,5,55"; // should be large, 10^6 is good
 // getline(cin, str1);
 cout<<"the old string " << str1 << endl;
 fastRemoveStuff(str1, ',');
 cout<<"the new string " << str1 << endl;
}
```

Comment: This is much less efficient than the original solution.

Comment: @Ben: What does it matter how efficient the original solution was?  It didn't produce correct results.  I can make very efficient algorithms too if I don't have to care about getting the answer right.

Comment: The original algorithm is easily fixed by setting the end of the string with `resize` instead of appending NUL, and retains its good performance.

Comment: Your new code is quite nice, taking advantage of memcpy and all its optimizations.  I think you can get rid of the temporary buffer by using memmove, but even that has questionable benefit as memmove may not be as well tuned as memcpy.

Comment: @Ben, from my investigations - it appears to me that library architects have, at least in gcc variants and Visual C++, included some considerable optimization into memchr(). From the Visual C++(9) disassembly (iirc) they even aligned memory accesses to 16 byte (or so) boundaries. So the major 'trick' here seems to be the inconspicuous  use of memchr() ;-)

Answer (score 1):

My own procedural version:

```
#include <string>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

string Remove( const string & s, char c  ) {

    string r;
    r.reserve( s.size() );

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++ ) {
        if ( s[i] != c ) {
            r += s[i];
        }
    }

    return r;
}

int main() {
    assert( Remove( "Foo,Bar,Zod", ',' ) == "FooBarZod" );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the program:

```
void main()
{
  int  i ;
  char  n[20] ;

  clrscr() ;

  printf("Enter a number. ") ;
  gets(n) ;

  printf("Number without comma is:") ;
  for(i=0 ; n[i]!='\0' ; i++)
    if(n[i] != ',')
      putchar(n[i]) ;

  getch();
}
```

For detailed description you can refer this blog: http://tutorialsschool.com/c-programming/c-programs/remove-comma-from-string.php

The same has been discussed in this post: [How to remove commas from a string in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33290218/how-to-remove-commas-from-a-string-in-c/40110833#40110833)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if youre planing to read from a file using c++. I found a method, while I dont think thats the best method though, but after I came to these forums to search for help before, I think its time to contribute with my effort aswell.

Look, here is the catch, what I'm going to present you is part of the source code of the map editor Im building on right now, that map editor obviously has the purpose to create maps for a 2D RPG game, the same style as the classic Pokemon games for example. But this code was more towards the development of the world map editor.

`int strStartPos = 0;
    int strSize = 0;
    int arrayPointInfoDepth = 0;

```
for (int x = 0; x < (m_wMapWidth / (TileSize / 2)); x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < (m_wMapHeight / (TileSize / 2)); y++) {
        if (ss >> str) {


            for (int strIterator = 0; strIterator < str.length(); strIterator++) {
                if (str[strIterator] == ',') {`

                    Here we need to define the size of the string we want to extract after the previous comma and before the next comma

                    `strSize = strIterator - strStartPos;`
```

And here, we do the actual transformation, we give to the vector that is a 3D vector btw the string we want to extract at that moment

```
                    `m_wMapPointInfo[x][y][arrayPointInfoDepth] = str.substr(strStartPos, strSize);`
```

And here, we just define that starting position for the next small piece of the string we want to extract, so the +1 means that after the comma we just passed
                        `strStartPos = strIterator + 1;`

Here, well since my vector has only 6 postions that is defined by WorldMapPointInfos we need to increment the third dimension of the array and finally do a check point where if the info has arrived the number 6 then break the loop

```
                    arrayPointInfoDepth++;

                    if (arrayPointInfoDepth == WorldMapPointInfos) {
                        strStartPos = 0;
                        arrayPointInfoDepth = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }



    }
}
```

Either way on my code, think abt that the vector is just a string, thats all you need to know, hope this helps though :/

Full view:

```
int strStartPos = 0;
int strSize = 0;
int arrayPointInfoDepth = 0;

for (int x = 0; x < (m_wMapWidth / (TileSize / 2)); x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < (m_wMapHeight / (TileSize / 2)); y++) {
        if (ss >> str) {


            for (int strIterator = 0; strIterator < str.length(); strIterator++) {
                if (str[strIterator] == ',') {
                    strSize = strIterator - strStartPos;

                    m_wMapPointInfo[x][y][arrayPointInfoDepth] = str.substr(strStartPos, strSize);

                    strStartPos = strIterator + 1;

                    arrayPointInfoDepth++;

                    if (arrayPointInfoDepth == WorldMapPointInfos) {
                        strStartPos = 0;
                        arrayPointInfoDepth = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }



    }
}
```