# How to remove commas from a string in C

Tags: c, string, punctuation

Say I have a string of "10, 5, 3" How can I get rid of the commas so the string is just "10 5 3"? Should I be using strtok?

Comment: Uh, if that is a function of which you know how to use: yes. There are dozens of other solutions; best to stick with what you know.

Comment: Uh, if not, and you just want to replace the commas in the string with something else, then just walk a pointer down the string and `while (*p) if (*p == ',') *p++ = ' ';` to replace with a `space'. If you are talking about *removing* that character altogether, then you can do essentially the same thing, but copy the chars you want to keep to a new string.

Comment: Refer this: http://tutorialsschool.com/c-programming/c-programs/remove-comma-from-string.php

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
char *r, *w;
for (w = r = str; *r; r++) {
    if (*r != ',') {
        *w++ = *r;
    }
}
*w = '\0';
```

Comment: in true K & R style, unreadable, inscrutable, short, efficient :-)

Comment: A perfectly readable solution that avoids the temptation to plow headlong into sequence point problems.

Comment: Very instructive. I didn't know one could use pointers in such an elegant fashion.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new string with the same size (+1 for the terminating character) as your current string, copy each character one by one and replace ',' by ' '.

In a `for` loop you would have something like this :

```
if (old_string[i] == ',')
    new_string[i] = ' ';
else
    new_string[i] = old_string[i];
i++;
```

Then after the `for` loop, do not forget to add '\0' at the end of `new_string`.

Answer (score 1):

A minor simplification to [@melpomene](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33290353/2410359).
Do potential assignment first and then check for the null character.

```
const char *r = str;
char *w = str;
do {
  if (*r != ',') {
    *w++ = *r;
  }
} while (*r++);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?  (My C is slightly rustyish and I don't have a compiler handy, so pardon any syntax bloopers)

```
char *string_with_commas = getStringWithCommas();

char *ptr1, *ptr2;
ptr1 = ptr2 = string_with_commas;

while(*ptr2 != '\0')
{
    if(*ptr2 != ',') *ptr1++ = *ptr2++;
    else *ptr2++;
}

*ptr1 = '\0';
```

You could also use a different variable to store the results, but since the result string is guaranteed to be equal or lesser length than the source string, it should be safe to overwrite it as we go.

Comment: That looks like my solution, only with slightly weird code. (In particular, `else *ptr++;` would probably trigger compiler warnings.)

Comment: @melpomene: no, the missing semicolon  does that. But the code is inherently flawed; it *modifies* comma's - it changes them to `+` I think.

Comment: @Jongware Yes, this is after adding the missing `;`. :-) Where are you getting `+` from?

Comment: @Jongware No, it doesn't.

Comment: @melpomene: .... `*ptr2++;` does not? I find myself expecting that line to read just `ptr2++;`. Hold on, I'm going to give this one a go.

Comment: @Jongware Yes, the `*` has no effect. Which is why I'd expect a warning for that.

Comment: @melpomene: paint my hair red and call me O'Really. "warning: expression result unused" (and then it works after all). Removing the `*` makes it work correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the program:

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <conio.h>
    int main()
    {
      int  i ;
      char  n[20] ;

      printf("Enter a number. ") ;
    gets(n) ;
      printf("Number without comma is:") ;
      for(i=0 ; n[i]!='\0' ; i++)
        if(n[i] != ',')
          putchar(n[i]) ;

    }
```

For detailed description you can refer this blog: http://tutorialsschool.com/c-programming/c-programs/remove-comma-from-string.php

Comment: `gets` should never be used; it is inherently unsafe.